# Filter column combinations with maximum row value after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe where for every Sequence ID there are values for 
**Column Combinations `(SubSeq1, Duration1), (SubSeq2, Duration2), (SubSeq3, Duration3)`**

I want to filter the data as per below condition:

> for every individual Sequence ID which Column Combinations have the
>   highest Duration

```
Sequence    SubSeq1     Duration1  SubSeq2     Duration2  SubSeq3     Duration3
1001        145         0          125         53         458         33
1001        475         20         175         54         652         45
1001        685         57         687         77         254         88

1002        125         54         175         96         786         26
1002        475         21         467         32         526         32

1003        325         68         301         54         529         41
1003        125         97         325         85         872         78

1004        129         15         429         41         981         82
1004        547         47         577         52         543         83
1004        666         65         722         63         257         85
```

I want my result dataframe as below:

```
Sequence    SubSeq     Duration
1001        254         88
1002        175         96
1003        125         97
1004        257         85
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) first for one column `Sequence` and `Duration`, then sorting by multiple columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['SubSeq','Duration'], i='index', j='tmp')
        .sort_values(['Sequence','Duration'], ascending=[True, False])
        .drop_duplicates('Sequence')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   Sequence  SubSeq  Duration
0      1001     254        88
1      1002     175        96
2      1003     125        97
3      1004     257        85
```